# AWS EC2 standalone instance Windows , Can I include start stop schdule in cloud formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am already doing scale in scale out for auto scaling stack through scheduled actions.

I am in need of to auto start and stop for standalone EC2 ( not part of ASG)just wondering if CF support that ?

Comment: What do you mean with 'auto start and stop'? When should the EC2 machine start and when should it stop? What are the triggers to start and stop these machines?

Comment: As of now it is time based start of EC2 and stop of EC2. I want to put that schedule in Cloud formation ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AWS Instance Scheduler](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler/) to automate the starting and stopping of EC2 machines. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/deployment.html) you can find the documentation on how to set this up manually, [and there is also a nice tutorial to follow along if the documentation is a bit too heavy](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/stop-start-instance-scheduler/).

The AWS Instance Scheduler deployment can also be setup using CloudFormation. [AWS provides these examples as a starting point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/templates.html).

Comment: Thanks Titulum for pointing to instance scheduler, I will check feasibility if the service is approved and on boarded by security team in our organization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no capability in AWS (or CloudFormation) to schedule a start and stop of an instance.

However, you can code-up a simple solution using **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger an **AWS Lambda function** on a schedule. You could even use Tags to identify when to start/stop instances.

For some examples, see: [Simple EC2 Stopinator in Lambda - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/simple-ec2-stopinator-in-lambda-5goj)

Comment: Thanks John for confirming that there is no capability in Cloud formation to schedule start stop of EC2 which is not in ASG. Yup we can do write cloud watch and lambda to do the same or use system manager or instance scheduler as mentioned by Titulum.